# Yii установка

Tags: php, yii

Не могу установить, файл yiic.bat у меня не открывается, как быть? OC windows

Answer (score 1):

[yii-framework-mini-kurs.akail.ru](http://yii-framework-mini-kurs.akail.ru)

Установка Yii там есть. Пройдите по сылке и будет вам счастье)

Answer (score 1):

вот подробнейшая установка. надеюсь пригодится

http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/02/yii-yii-for-dummies.html

Answer (score 0):

Вот почитайте [С чего я начал. Установка Yii framework](http://psyhos.blogspot.com/2011/04/blog-post.html)

Цитата из ссылки:

> А сработало так: открыл cmd: Пуск -
> выполнить -cmd В открывшемся черном
> окне написал:
>
> Z:/usr/local/php5/php.exe
> z:/home/catalog.loc/www/framework/yiic
> webapp z:/home/catalog.loc/www/
>
> и нажал Enter программа спросила
> yes/no (действительно ли вы это
> желаете), я ответил yes и в папке
> Z:homecatalog.locwww создался мой
> первый сайт на Yii  Данная команда
> передала файлу php.exe задание создать
> новое приложение yii в папке
> z:/home/catalog.loc/www/ После этого я
> в браузере набрал адрес
> http://catalog.loc и увидел рузультат!

Answer (score 0):

Что значит не открывается? Вы скорее всего просто дважды кликаете по значку в папке, скрипт отрабатывает и тут же завершается. Попробуйте запускать через консоль.